# In GIMP, how to completely disable anti-aliasing/interpolation while scaling a selection?

Tags: gimp, resize, anti-aliasing

I'm trying to design something in GIMP that must have no anti-aliasing/interpolation at all. When I scale up, I want sharp edges with no blur.

I can disable anti-aliasing/interpolation while scaling up the entire image, but there is no corresponding way to turn it off while scaling up just a selection.

I want to scale up a selection so that the edges have no blur, no transparency, and no anti-aliasing or interpolation of any kind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to rotate, deform or scale a floating selection with the corresponding tools we have to set *Interpolation* to *None* in the *Tool Options* to avoid anti-aliasing.

[image]

Then a selection will be transformed with sharp edges but with aliasing, of course:

[image]